# $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is f.g. if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I want to prove the following theorem, I came up to some point but I need some help to finish the proof:

**Theorem.**$\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is finitely generated $\implies$ $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.

**Proof.** Let $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is generated by $S=\{1=\beta_0,\beta_1, \dots, \beta_k\}$.

Now I define $\varphi:S \rightarrow \alpha S$.  If $\alpha \beta_i = \alpha\beta_j$ for some $i\ne j \in \{0,\dots, k\}$ then $\alpha(\beta_i - \beta_j)=0 \implies (\beta_i -\beta_j)=0 $ since $\alpha,\beta_0, \dots, \beta_k \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and  $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is an integral domain since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain. Thus, $\beta_i = \beta_j$ so $\varphi$ is injective and $|S|<\infty \implies$ it is surjective.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 4):

If $\mathbb Z [\alpha]$ is finitely generated, then there is some $n\in \mathbb N$, such that $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots , \alpha^n$ generates $\mathbb{Z} [\alpha]$. (This follows as $(\alpha^i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ generates $\mathbb Z [\alpha]$)
Now write $\alpha^{n+1}= \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i \alpha^i$, so $\alpha^{n+1}- \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i \alpha^i=0$. Thus $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: Dear @MatheiBoulomenos, I don't think we are allowed to assume that $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^n$ generates $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ here. All we know in the beginning is that there are some $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$ that generate $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$.

Comment: Write $\beta_k = \sum_{i=0}^{m_k} a_{ik} \alpha^i$, for $k=1, \dots n$. Then choose $m = \max(m_1, \dots, m_n)$, then $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^m$ generates $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, because the module generated by  $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^m$ contains a generating set of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, so it generates it.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks!

Comment: How do we write $\beta_k = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_k}a_{ik}\alpha^{i}$?

Comment: @Ninja Every element of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ has an expression as a polynomial in $\alpha$ with integer coefficients. This is just the definition of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$

Answer (score 1):

Every $\beta_0,...,\beta_k$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients on $\alpha$. Take $n\in\mathbb{N}$ greater than all the dregrees of $\beta_1(\alpha),...,\beta_n(\alpha)$. Then $\alpha^n=\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_i\beta_i(\alpha)$ for some $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. The polynomial $p(x):=x^n-\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_i\beta_i(x)$ is monic with degree $n$ and such that $p(\alpha)=0$, so $\alpha$ is algebraic.